# Error al abrir un Proyecto en laravel

Tags: php, html5, laravel

soy nuevo en laravel, tengo un problema. 
Tengo un proyecto que me pasaron de una PC y la estoy usando en la mia. Ya instale el composer e instale laravel, cuando trato de abrirlo mediante php artisan serve en la direccion de mi proyecto en htdocs en xampp me manda estos errores:

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\TS_Proyect\public/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TS_Proyect\public\index.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\TS_Proyect\public/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TS_Proyect\public\index.php on line 22

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si estas manejando tu proyecto desde un servidor como XAMPP, no veo la necesidad de utilizar la sentencia `php artisan serve` puesto que con que pongas a correr el apache podrás acceder a tu proyecto desde el navegador

Comment: Era un error en la ruta del archivo, gracias igual.

Answer (score 2):

Esos error es porque no has instalado las librerias,

ejecuta en la raiz de tu proyecto

```
composer install
```

seguido tendrás que copiar el archivo '.env.example' a '.env'

luego ejecuta

```
php artisan key:generate
```

configura la conexión a la base de datos.

```
php artisan migrate (si tiene seeders utiliza  --seed)
```

y ya deberías de poder visualizar tu proyecto.